# Create dynamically contexts for com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer (Java)

Tags: java, httpserver

I need to handle HTTP requests using `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` which requests are triggered by the following URL schema:

`http://somehost:9000/<var>/<service>`

`<var>` is a parameter which is passed to the `<service>`

`<service>` is a predefined service that the server provides

The problem is that the context path is not known at compile time (because of the `<var>`) so I can not just call `createContext(String path, HttpHandler handler)`. How can I bind this kind of 'dynamic' context to a specific `HttpHandler` instance?

Comment: handle "/" then adapt in the handler?

Comment: I was looking for more... let say... streamlined solution but it seems this is my only option. @RC., can you add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can handle "/" and adapt the handler, something like this:

```
createContext("/", new HttpHandler(){
    @Override
    void handle(final HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
         // use getRequestURI()
    }
});
```

see also [`HttpExchange#getRequestURI()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange.html#getRequestURI())

Comment: Is there no other way of parsing the path parameters ?

Answer (score 11):

I know this is a very old thread, but for anyone who finds it, I hope my answer will help.

I was recently creating a similar server where I needed a URL handler for the form /person/[id]/[location] where "id" and "location" were variable values. But I also needed a /person handler.

I'm sure there's documentation on this somewhere, but I discovered that creatContext will assign a handler to whatever it first recognizes.

What that means is that all I had to do was define a handler for "/person" and inside that handler, check for the [id] and [location] values. If there were those values, the handler would do something different, if not, it would just do the /person handler.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Can you provide a code example of how you checked for the `id` and `location` values?

Comment: That's a good question! I did this for a school project and don't think I have the code any more unfortunately. I probably used getRequestURI and I think I remember separating the string based on '/'s to see if there was an id or location. Sorry!